# How do I construct a syntax-only match-finder tool?

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree, clang-ast-matchers

I am building an ASTMatcher-based tool that I would like to run over my sources:

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    CommonOptionsParser OptionsParser(argc, argv, MyToolCategory);
    ClangTool Tool(OptionsParser.getCompilations(),
                   OptionsParser.getSourcePathList());
    MatchFinder Finder;

    // Repeated calls to Finder.addMatcher(...);

    Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory(&Finder).get());

    // Handle the results of the matching.
}
```

Running this over a source file that depends on other headers yields the following error:

```
~$ /path/to/my/tool /path/to/my/file.cpp --
/path/to/my/file.cpp:8:10: fatal error: 'string' file not found
#include <string>
         ^~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Error while processing /path/to/my/file.cpp.
```

I do not want to include any other headers in this processing, lest my matchers find content in those headers that I do not want to handle.

I tried passing `-fsyntax_only` to the tool, but I get the same result as above:

```
 ~$ /path/to/my/tool /path/to/my/file.cpp -- -fsyntax-only
```

I noticed in the [ASTMatcher tutorial](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibASTMatchersTutorial.html) that there is a `clang::SyntaxOnlyAction`. However, I have been unable to figure out how `MatchFinder` and `SyntaxOnlyAction` can be used in conjunction with one another. Likewise, I have been able to do an AST dump from the command line of the same file, no problem, so I know it's possible.

Is it possible to configure a MatchFinder-based tool to honor the syntax-only behavior?

Comment: Wouldn't syntax-checking still involve processing `#include`? (The meaning of something like `foo bar;` is completely different if the header says `typedef int foo;` vs. if the header says `#define foo 3 +`.)

Comment: @ruakh I would be okay with the output using `foo` without knowing what its underlying type is. That's the point of the `syntax-only` check, as far as I know: it's able to validate the syntax even if the header includes types the parser has not seen before.

Comment: @ruakh I am okay with the syntax possibly being misinterpreted. I am interested in being able to match and process the same traversal that I see with the `-fsyntax-only -ast-dump` flags.

Comment: The traversal that you see with the `-fsyntax-only -ast-dump` flags will depend on the contents of included headers. I don't think Clang has any support for trying to "guess" how to interpret syntax without reading the headers.

Comment: @ruakh Okay, thanks for the info. How do I limit the scope of the matching, then, to just the contents of the original file? I don't want to match against the contents of the standard library, or other headers I include. Is this possible?

Comment: I honestly don't know, but if nothing else, it seems like you should be able to filter in your own matcher code by examining the `clang_getCursorLocation` to determine what file you're in. (You'll have to decide how you want to handle nodes that are split among includes; hopefully that should be rare.)

Comment: @ruakh Thanks for all the help! I was able to figure out what file the node originated in with the `getBeginLoc` API. For the time being I'll assume if the node begins in the file(s) passed to the tool, they should be handled.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this @fbrereto?

Comment: @Andrespch Yes and no. The solution was to do the necessary path inclusion to result in a successful compilation pass over the file. As I mentioned in an above comment, I filtered the actions I took on the result based on where the found symbols lived (i.e., in the file I was originally intent on processing.)